# this type of routing is possible in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a database with categories and post, at present I access him through their controllers from the way:
"/category/id" and "/post/id"

but now I want to access with next path:
"/category_name/post_name"

The logical thing would be to use "/application/config/routes.php"
and create: `$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'post';`

The problem is that in my wanted path is possible the subcategories like "/category1_name/category2_name/post_name"

I am trying to create the next route:
`$route['(\w|/)*'] = 'route';`
but it generates a problem with my other controllers and is not recommend calling a controller from another controller.

Is it possible to generate my want path?

Comment: Which kind of "problem" with other controllers are you facing?

Comment: when i am use `$route['(\w|/)*'] = 'route';` i can't access to my other controllers. Because all path is redirect to route controller

Comment: Then you should think about prioritizing rules (define that specific rule after all others) or introduce a specific prefix for that rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I improved the code, I access to variables outside from anonymous function with use(), set a maximum quantity of categories in the url and I generate array with controller names, in case the path is a controller path, it routing to him, if not, the routing to route controller.

code in `"application/config/routes.php"`:

```
$my_controllers = array();
$directory = opendir(APPPATH."controllers");
while($file = readdir($directory)){
    if($file != "index.html" && $file != "." && $file != "..") array_push($my_controllers, strtolower(str_replace(".php", '', $file)));
}
$max_categories = 5; //if your need more add $params in the anonymous function, if you need less, only change the num
$temp_path = "";
for($i=0;$i<=$max_categories;$i++){
    if($i!=0) $temp_path .= '/';
    $temp_path .= '(:any)';

    $route[$temp_path] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5="") use ($i,$my_controllers){
        $temp_cond = false;
        foreach ($my_controllers as $value) {
            $temp_cond = $temp_cond || $param0 == $value;
        }
        if($temp_cond){ 
            $temp_return = $param0;
            for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
                $temp_return .= '/';
                $varvar = "param$j";
                $temp_return .= $$varvar;
            }
        return $temp_return;    
        }
        else return 'route';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
way: "/category/id" and "/post/id"
```

you cannot rout any at first place in order to achieve your url

```
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'post/load/category/$1'; 
$route['post/(:any)'] = 'post/load/post/$1';
```

and at your controller post create a method load with 2 parameter.. like

```
<?php

class Post extends CI_Controller {
 function load($parameter1 , $parameter2 )
 {
  echo $parameter1."<br>";
  echo $parameter2;
 }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment i trying this:

How exist subcategories, the number of categories in the path is variable, how the url is not infinte i defined a maximous of categories in the path and I include this code in the `"application/config/routes.php"`:

```
$route['(:any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0;
    else return 'route';
};
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0.'/'.$param1;
    else return 'route';
};

$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0.'/'.$param1.'/'.$param2;
    else return 'route';
};

$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/:(any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0.'/'.$param1.'/'.$param2.'/'.$param3;
    else return 'route';
};

$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0.'/'.$param1.'/'.$param2.'/'.$param3.'/'.$param4;
    else return 'route';
};

$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0.'/'.$param1.'/'.$param2.'/'.$param3.'/'.$param4.'/'.$param5;
    else return 'route';
};
```

It is very ugly code but functional. I am trying improve it with a loop that will set the max of categories with a variable, but i have problems with variables inside of callback function.

Example:

```
$i = 4;
$route['(:any)'] = function ($param0="",$param1="",$param2="",$param3="",$param4="",$param5=""){
    global $i;
    if($param0 == "user" || $param0 == "home" || $param0 == "post" || $param0 == "user") return $param0;
    else return 'route';
};
```

Inside the callback function $i is empty,